# Alterar TabIndex

Tags: c#, winforms

Como faço para voltar o **`TabIndex`** de um **`Form`** para a uma determinada posição?

Tentei usar o **`this.ActiveControl.TabIndex = 0;`**, mas não deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Isso não é possível. Aliás, da forma que você está fazendo, está tentando **alterar** o TabIndex do controle ativo, sendo que o que precisa é justamente **alterar o controle** atualmente ativo.

O que você pode fazer é ***setar*** a propriedade `ActiveControl` do Form.

Por exemplo:

```
this.ActiveControl = this.textBoxBusca;
```

Se quiser **muito** selecionar o controle pelo seu TabIndex, você trabalhar com LINQ pra isso. Só pra constar, acho essa abordagem extremamente desnecessária.

```
var controle = this.Controls.First(c => c.TabIndex == 0);
this.ActiveControl = controle;
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo exatamente com eu queria.